# Unexpected Identifier Error for my function with a closure

Tags: javascript

I am receiving an error message for "unexpected identifier" and I am not sure why.  The error message says it is for the line "getDOMstrings function () {".  Does anyone know why I am getting an error?

```
//UI CONTROLLER
var UIController = (function()  {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: ".add__type",
    inputDescription: ".add__description",
    inputValue: ".add__value",
    inputBtn: '.add__btn'
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return{
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,  // will be either inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
      }
    }
    getDOMstrings: function () {
      return DOMstrings
    }

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no comma between the two functions.

```
  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return{
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,  // will be either inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
      }
    }, // Added this guy
    getDOMstrings: function () {
      return DOMstrings
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma at the end of the closing `}` on the previous line.